# Как начать использовать MS SQL Server 2012 исключительно из командной строки?

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, sql

Только начал изучать SQL, не могу приступить к использованию MS SQL Server.
При попытке выполнить "sqlcmd" в командной строке получаю:

> HResult 0x2, Level 16, State 1
> Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or in
> stance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
> . Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i
> f SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see
> SQL Server Books Online..
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

Comment: Выполните `sqlcmd /?` и посмотрите, какие ему нужны аргументы

Answer (score 2):

Передавайте в явном виде сервер и логин:

```
sqlcmd -S (local)\sqlexpress -U sa
```

Answer (score 2):

Очень похоже на то, что вы пытаетесь подключится к сетевому экземпляру SQL Server, на котором отключен [SQL Server Browser Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087(v=sql.130).aspx). Если моя догадка истинна, то для решения вашей проблемы достаточно запустить данный сервис.